# How to uniquely number subnodes of a parent

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like so

```
ID               Node                  ParentID
1                 A                        0
2                 B                        1
3                 C                        1
4                 D                        2
5                 E                        2
6                 F                        3
7                 G                        3
8                 H                        3 
9                 I                        4
10                J                        4
11                K                        10
12                L                        11
```

I need a query to generate a 'position' field with the order that a node appears within its parent. Example below

```
ID               Node                  ParentID                  Positon
1                 A                        0                         0
2                 B                        1                         0
3                 C                        1                         1
4                 D                        2                         0
5                 E                        2                         1
6                 F                        3                         0
7                 G                        3                         1
8                 H                        3                         2 
9                 I                        4                         0
10                J                        4                         1
11                K                        10                        0
12                L                        11                        0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  *
,       row_number() over (partition by ParentID order by ID) - 1 as Position
from    YourTable
```

As an update query:

```
update  yt
set     Position = nr
from    (
        select  *
        ,       row_number() over (partition by ParentID order by ID) - 1 rn
        from    YourTable
        ) yt
```

Comment: Looks good, how would I write that as an UPDATE query to store position in the original table

Answer (score 2):

To update position in the original table join it to already suggested statement, either as sub-query or CTE:

```
;with cte (ID, Pos)
as (
    select ID, row_number() over (partition by ParentID order by ID) - 1
    from [Table]
)
update T
set T.Position = cte.Pos
from [Table] T
    join cte on cte.ID = T.ID
```

Comment: T1 could not be bound. Typo?

Comment: You can actually omit the join.  SQL Server is smart enough to remember the tables's row identifier (either a PK or a rowid) through a subquery.

Comment: Andomar. Interested, can to show an example using the query above?

Comment: @Andomar, I got your point (it's like updating table via its view, just inline and surely more compact and better performance wise than join)